# How to toggle letter cases in a region in emacs

Tags: emacs, elisp

How can I toggle the case of letters (switch uppercase letters to lowercase and lowercase letters to uppercase) of a region's text in Emacs?

There are listed commands for conversion but nothing for toggling.

**Example:**

PLease toggLE MY LETTER case

should become:

plEASE TOGGle my letter CASE

Comment: Looks like several of the attempted answers fail to see a use case for what you are actually asking for, so they solve a different problem instead.  Can you explain where this would be useful, if only for our amusement?

Comment: This might not be too common, but I switched case by mistake (terminals and non-terminals in a grammar file) and thought there could be a command for reversing them. Could happen maybe with markup and values and similar cases. I'm thinking now if there was such a command, it could be used for both upcase and downcase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote it for you; it did not have thorough testing, but it appears to do what you seek.

The logic behind it is to loop over every single character in the text. If the character is equal to the character in downcase, append it to the return string in upcase. If not, append it in downcase. At the end, delete region and insert the return string.

It works immediate on a page of text, though I'd be wary to use it on huge texts (should be fine still).

```
(defun toggle-case ()
  (interactive)
  (when (region-active-p)
    (let ((i 0)
      (return-string "")
      (input (buffer-substring-no-properties (region-beginning) (region-end))))
      (while (< i (- (region-end) (region-beginning)))
    (let ((current-char (substring input i (+ i 1))))
      (if (string= (substring input i (+ i 1)) (downcase (substring input i (+ i 1))))
          (setq return-string
            (concat return-string (upcase (substring input i (+ i 1)))))
        (setq return-string
          (concat return-string (downcase (substring input i (+ i 1)))))))
    (setq i (+ i 1)))
      (delete-region (region-beginning) (region-end))
      (insert return-string))))
```

Answer (score 6):

You can do it with a regexp substitution:

```
M-x replace-regexp RET
\([[:upper:]]+\)?\([[:lower:]]+\)? RET
\,(concat (downcase (or \1 "")) (upcase (or \2 ""))) RET
```

It's up to you to bind a key to this.

Comment: There is an extra paren at end in the replacement but this one takes the award

Comment: Yes, I noticed (and corrected) it just shortly before your comment.

Answer (score 3):

Commands `upcase-region`, `downcase-region`, and`capitalize-region` are not toggles, and are perhaps the "conversion" commands you referred to.  Here is a command that cycles among them.

```
 (defvar cycle-region-capitalization-last 'upper)
 (defun cycle-region-capitalization (&optional msgp)
  "Cycle the region text among uppercase, lowercase and capitalized (title case)."
  (interactive "p")
  (setq cycle-region-capitalization-last
        (case cycle-region-capitalization-last
          (upper  (call-interactively #'downcase-region)   'lower)
          (lower  (call-interactively #'capitalize-region) 'title)
          (title  (call-interactively #'upcase-region)     'upper)))
  (when msgp (message "Region is now %scase" cycle-region-capitalization-last)))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you mean letter case, then this function works nicely:  http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/modernization_upcase-word.html

```
(defun toggle-letter-case ()
   "Toggle the letter case of current word or text selection.
   Toggles between: “all lower”, “Init Caps”, “ALL CAPS”."
   (interactive)
   (let (p1 p2 (deactivate-mark nil) (case-fold-search nil))
    (if (region-active-p)
        (setq p1 (region-beginning) p2 (region-end))
      (let ((bds (bounds-of-thing-at-point 'word) ) )
        (setq p1 (car bds) p2 (cdr bds)) ) )
    (when (not (eq last-command this-command))
      (save-excursion
        (goto-char p1)
        (cond
         ((looking-at "[[:lower:]][[:lower:]]") (put this-command 'state "all lower"))
         ((looking-at "[[:upper:]][[:upper:]]") (put this-command 'state "all caps") )
         ((looking-at "[[:upper:]][[:lower:]]") (put this-command 'state "init caps") )
         ((looking-at "[[:lower:]]") (put this-command 'state "all lower"))
         ((looking-at "[[:upper:]]") (put this-command 'state "all caps") )
         (t (put this-command 'state "all lower") ) ) ) )
    (cond
     ((string= "all lower" (get this-command 'state))
      (upcase-initials-region p1 p2) (put this-command 'state "init caps"))
     ((string= "init caps" (get this-command 'state))
      (upcase-region p1 p2) (put this-command 'state "all caps"))
     ((string= "all caps" (get this-command 'state))
      (downcase-region p1 p2) (put this-command 'state "all lower")) )
    ) )
```

Comment: Upper to lower and lower to upper for each letter in the region.

Answer (score 0):

I liked the other answer's  technique of comparing `this-command` and `last-command`,
so I've incorporated it into my old function. Here's the result:

```
(defun upcase-word-toggle ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((bounds (bounds-of-thing-at-point 'symbol))
        beg end
        regionp)
    (if (eq this-command last-command)
        (setq regionp (get this-command 'regionp))
      (put this-command 'regionp nil))
    (cond 
      ((or (region-active-p) regionp)
       (setq beg (region-beginning)
             end (region-end))
       (put this-command 'regionp t))
      (bounds 
       (setq beg (car bounds)
             end (cdr bounds)))
      (t 
       (setq beg (point)
             end (1+ beg))))
    (save-excursion
      (goto-char (1- beg))
      (and (re-search-forward "[A-Za-z]" end t)
           (funcall (if (char-upcasep (char-after)) 
                        'downcase-region 
                      'upcase-region)
                    beg end)))))

(defun char-upcasep (letter)
  (eq letter (upcase letter)))

(global-set-key (kbd "C->") 'upcase-word-toggle)
```

Comment: Can't test your code: Symbol's function definition is void: char-upcasep